# cin.ignore() if there were characters

Tags: c++, cin

I have 2 player in 2 terminal.
when It is the turn of player1 he enter a char and it's ok.
but when It is the turn of player2 if player 1 enter a char befor his turn, in this case, when it is his turn automatically that char is entered.
if I use cin.ignore(), if player 1 dosnt do any think and dosnt enter a char When it 's not his turn he has to enter char 2 time ( 1 time to ignore and 1 time to cin ) and it's bad.
I want to write a code that ignore char if a char (or 2 or more char) was in terminal before. and if there were no char, dosnt ignore.
I uploded a picture that shows the char automatically entered for player 1 because he entered "a" befor his turn. (a bit of code exist in this picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofo9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read the full line of input. Take only the first character, ignore the rest.

Something like:

```
std::string input;
std::getline( std::cin, input );
char move = input[0];
```

This code obviously doesn't do error checking, so, you might want to add that in.

Comment: When it is the turn of playe2, maybe player 1 enter 20 line of string. When it is the player1's turn, i want to ignore everything and get new character from player 1.